# Отправка e-mail из приложения на C++

Tags: c++, email, библиотеки, smtp, library

Подскажите, какие библиотеки лучше использовать для отправки сообщений email из приложения на C++. Задача стоит тривиальнейшая, необходимо отправлять новым пользователям подтверждения о регистрации. В приоритете легкий вес и минимальные зависимости. Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы посоветовал libcurl. По мне так весьма функционально.
пример отправки по smtp: 
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html

Comment: Так же рекомендуют vmime https://www.vmime.org/category/Support